# Is there a way to know the template engine of a web site?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, pug, ejs

I'm retro engineering a couple of web apps to figure out which technologies are behind them so I can know which one I can use or learn to build my own web app

So, going through the app I can see that it's based on **NodeJs and ExpressJS** and luckily I know both of them.

But what I **can't** figure out is the template engine, there's a lot of template engines that are really friendly to Express(**Jade, EJS, HandleBars, etc...**)

So I was wondering if there is a way to know which template engine is used on a web site

Comment: Not directly, but you might see some signs of one. For example, a website using plain PHP will probably have seemingly nonsensical whitespace in the source. Jade/Pug on the other hand outputs very consistent output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not normally.  The whole point of a template engine is to replace special characters with user facing content so that precludes the type of hints one would need to determine the template engine.  One would need to see the server side source code to really know.

Comment: yes sure, I just thought that a certain template engine would have a kind of signature or an additional string that might betray it so we can spot which engine process the code.
But, yes I completely get the purpose of template engine